# react native with firebase onDisconnect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I build react native app and I'm trying to make event when user close the app, so it update in firebase the status to 'offline'.
what I do is

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Router from './src/Router'
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            uid: '',
            userStatusDatabaseRef :'',
            userStatusFirestoreRef: ''
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData().then((user) => {

            var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            console.log('uid', uid)
            var userStatusDatabaseRef = firebase.database().ref('status/' + uid);

            var isOfflineForDatabase = {
                state: 'offline',
                last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            };

            var isOnlineForDatabase = {
                state: 'online',
                last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            };

            var userStatusDatabaseRef = firebase.database().ref('status/' + uid);

            var userStatusFirestoreRef = firebase.firestore().doc('status/' + uid);


            var isOfflineForFirestore = {
                state: 'offline',
                last_changed: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            };

            var isOnlineForFirestore = {
                state: 'online',
                last_changed: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            };

            const connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
            connectedRef.on("value", function (snap) {
                // validate if connection is established
                if (snap.val() === true) {
                    // remove the user's record on the disconnect
                    userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(()=>{
                        userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForFirestore);

                    })
                    // then request user to enter their name
                } else {
                    userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);

                }
            });
            this.setState({userStatusDatabaseRef,userStatusFirestoreRef,uid})
        })

    }
    render() {
        return <Router />
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        var isOfflineForFirestore = {
            state: 'offline',
            last_changed: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        };

        this.state.userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);

    }
}
```

first, I would like to understand when onDisconnect fire and what is do. second, when i navigate to other screen, it fire me and that's not what I'm looking for, only when user close app from each screen. I don't want to duplicate the code and write in each component because it's not right coding. what I'm looking for event from each screen/component that user that can update in firebase offline or online

I changed my code and it update only in firebase and not the firestore

```
 const connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");

            // validate if connection is established
            if (snap.val() === true) {
                userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
                userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase)

                // remove the user's record on the disconnect
                userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().remove((error)=>{
                    userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);
                    userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);

                })
                // then request user to enter their name
            } else {

                userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);

            }
        });
```

why it's not set the value also in firestore to 'offline'

```
 userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().remove((error)=>{
                    userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore); // it update only in firebase
                    userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);

                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you establish a firebase `onDisconnect()` operation, the operation is initiated on **FireBase RealTime Sever**. It checks if your user can perform write operations and pass callbacks for the same if invalid.

It also checks the connection status. When your connection is **lost** **or timed out** or deliberately **closed** by the client, the connection is invoked.

The second part of your question depends upon the *nature of your navigation, whether the component umounts thereby disconnecting from the server* or *whether it is nested inside the same*.

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect) , you can use the **remove** operation

*Ensures the data at this location is deleted when the client is disconnected (due to closing the browser, navigating to a new page, or network issues)*

```
 YourFireBaseRef.onDisconnect().remove((error) => {
      // Do some stuff
    });
```

Also another thing to note is

`onDisconnect` operations are only triggered once. If you want an operation to occur each time a `disconnect` occurs, you'll need to re-establish the **onDisconnect operations each time you reconnect**.

Comment: How can i see its invoked? Its not fire me when connection is lost.. im looking a way to make callback and write to firebase when lost connection or user close a

Comment: Updated , you may use `remove` to check it, also check the note.

Comment: I changed it by your recommend and it remove only in firebase, I want it to update in firestore to 'offline after it remove in firebase

Comment: Check if you've got the write permissions and also if the doc exists `userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore, { merge: true })` to merge the docs.